# VS Code execute selection to IPython shell in terminal (no notebook)

Tags: python, ipython, visual-studio-code

I wanted to use IPython interactive in VSC (not using a notebook). By using a keybiding for workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText, I can successfully execute a selection to a python interactive shell, but with iPython it fails to run the cell and I have to change selection to the terminal and press enter.

[image]

Here's my keybidings.json file:

```
[
    {
        "key": "ctrl+enter",
        "command": "workbench.action.terminal.runSelectedText"
    }
]
```

Any help to solve this is much appreciated! Ideally, a keybinding configuration that includes an extra enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this problem when I upgraded IPython to version 7.30.1
The solution I found is that add `"--simple-prompt"`, this is not perfect (just no color theme or auto completion), but at very least, you don't need to press enter when sending codes to run.

Comment: Indeed it creates other nuisances, but it does solve the issue!

Answer (score 0):

IPython is not officially supported by the Python extension and this is part of the reason: IPython's design simply  requires you to press Enter an extra time based on how VS Code sends text into the terminal.

Comment: I see, that explains it. But I guess better way to putt what I'm looking for is a keybinding to add that Enter an extra time for me.

Comment: I don't know if you can make that work. Any keybinding to send the line to the terminal will probably execute a newline in the text buffer and not the terminal (assuming you can combine the two things in the first place).https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_keyboard-shortcuts-editor is the docs for customizing keyboard shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with IPython's autoindent feature. You can disable this by passing `--no-autoindent` when launching IPython (i.e. `ipython --no-autoindent`).

edit: added gif.

[image]

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. :/
Maybe your setup is slightly different? Are you using the same keybiding?

Comment: The keybinding shouldn't matter, it's the command itself that triggers the action. I've added screen capture using "Run Selected Text" from the command palette to demonstrate. Also note that you need highlight an empty line at the end of the code finish the statement in Ipython.

Comment: I see, but  I think `--no-autoindent` solves a different problem than I have. 
What I was hoping to get is the same behavior as python interactive shell, which is to run a single line statement by default when calling `runSelectedText`. Even when selecting an extra blank line I still need to select the terminal and press enter.

Answer (score 0):

I was annoyed by this quirk in vs-code too.

I noticed that when using a python virtual environment (I use `pipenv`) my selected line was executed in an `Ipython` terminal and no extra <kbd>Enter</kbd> key press was needed.

To reproduce or test out:

1. Launch VS Code
2. Open a python file and a terminal window
3. In the terminal run `pipenv shell` (requires `pip install pipenv && pipenv install ipython`)
4. Then in the terminal run `ipython` (or `ipython --no-autoindent`)
5. Select a line in your python file and from a vs-code command palette execute `Terminal: Run Selected Text in Active Terminal` (or use a keyboard shortcut)

[image: screenshot of python window and terminal window]

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit late, but I think I've found the solution to this annoying behavior:

1. Install the [Multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension.
2. Copy the following code to your `keybindings.json` file:

```json
[
    {
        "key": "shift+enter",
        "command": "-python.execSelectionInTerminal",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !findInputFocused && !jupyter.ownsSelection && !notebookEditorFocused && !replaceInputFocused && editorLangId == 'python'"
    },
    {   
        // Use this when IPython gets borked using "python.execSelectionInTerminal"
        "key": "shift+enter",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
            "interval": 40,
            "sequence": [
                "python.execSelectionInTerminal",
                "workbench.action.terminal.focus",
                "workbench.action.terminal.scrollToBottom",
                {
                    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
                    "args": { "text": "\u000D" } // This basically "presses enter"
                },
                "workbench.action.focusActiveEditorGroup"
            ]
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !findInputFocused && !replaceInputFocused && editorLangId == 'python'"
    }
]
```

3. Restart the Vscode terminal.